# How can I push single element in existing array of JSON?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am having a array in which I want to add a single json element. Here is the array.

```
"six": {
            "donnes_table_two": [
                {
                    "denomination_de_vente": "value",
                    "marques": "value"
                },
                {
                    "denomination_de_vente": "value",
                    "marques": "value"
                }
            ]
        }
```

I want to add ID in every array element after adding the id it would look it.

```
"six": {
            "donnes_table_two": [
                {   "id" : "1",
                    "denomination_de_vente": "value",
                    "marques": "value"
                },
                {  
                    "id" = "1",
                    "denomination_de_vente": "value",
                    "marques": "value"
                }
            ]
        }
```

ID would be same in every element. Can I do it without using loop? Is there any PHP function?

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Comment: 1. `Can I do it without using loop?`. No 2. `Is there any PHP function?`  No there is not any function in php to do it without loop.

Comment: Where does PHP come in the picture? You say you have an array, but then give a part of a JSON. Do you want to add a property to a PHP object? Do you want to add a property to a JavaScript plain object? Or do you want to manipulate JSON directly? It is not clear...

Comment: Do you want id 1 on all elements? Doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: @trincot I am working on PHP and I am new to it. There is JSON and inside that JSON there is an array which contains JSON. Now I wanted to add one element of JSON inside the array of JSON. The key of that element would be "id" and value would be same for each element. This is confusing but this is best I can do.

Comment: What is the purpose of the id = 1 if all is supposed to be 1? Sounds like a xy problem

Comment: @Andreas That id is foreign key so it will be same in each record
$id =  $this->db->insert_id();  (last inserted record id)

Comment: Just to be sure what you mean with JSON: JSON is a text format. Are we talking about text here? Or do you mean a PHP data structure? In the latter case, could you remove all references to JSON, and show the PHP code that has the assignment of this array to a variable? If it *is* JSON, then please post valid JSON. An object structure should start with a brace, not with `"six": `

Comment: @trincot 

$this->db->insert_batch('donnes_table_one', $data['six']['donnes_table_two']);

Before entering that array to database I want to add an element

Comment: Can you please edit your question and remove all references to JSON, and add this information? Your mention of JSON is confusing people, as also can be seen from the answers. Your question has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: @Alex I did it with 3 for loops but it is way more complicated

Comment: Also, can you share that code with `3 for loops` ?

Comment: @niklesh there is a function to do such work without looping. Check [array_walk](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

Comment: @bansi : I have also given solution As I felt it can be done through `str_replace` at once without going to each element as OP asked `Can I do it without using loop?`. but still I think `array_walk` will go to each elements. will not ? correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another method uses [array_walk](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

```
 $arr = json_decode( '{"six": {
        "donnes_table_two": [
            {
                "denomination_de_vente": "value",
                "marques": "value"
            },
            {
                "denomination_de_vente": "value",
                "marques": "value"
            }
        ]
    }}', true);
    array_walk ($arr['six']['donnes_table_two'], function (&$item)
          { $item['id'] = 1;});

     echo json_encode ($arr,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
```

demo [here](https://eval.in/1089436)

Answer (score 0):

```
$json_value = '{
                  "six": {
                            "donnes_table_two": [
                                {
                                    "denomination_de_vente": "value",
                                    "marques": "value"
                                },
                                {
                                    "denomination_de_vente": "value",
                                    "marques": "value"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
              }';

$array_value = json_decode($json_value, true);      

 $total_inner_arrays = 1;
 for($i=0; $i<=$total_inner_arrays;$i++)
 {
    $array_value['six']['donnes_table_two'][$total_inner_arrays]['id'] = 1; 
 } 

$final_result = json_encode($array_value);
```

Comment: He don't want to do it by loop as OP says `without using loop`

Comment: "Can I do it without using loop?" is probably a misunderstood requirement from the asker.

Answer (score 0):

So If it's just a string. then you can use PHP `str_replace` to add `"id":"1"` just before `"denomination_de_vente"`, like below example

```
<?php
$json = '{"six":{
            "donnes_table_two": [
                {
                    "denomination_de_vente": "value",
                    "marques": "value"
                },
                {
                    "denomination_de_vente": "value",
                    "marques": "value"
                }
            ]
        }}';

//$json = json_encode($yourObject);//if it is an php object or Array
$json = str_replace('"denomination_de_vente"','"id":"1","denomination_de_vente"',$json);
print_r(json_decode($json,true));// here 'true' to get result as array in your case
?>
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/1089424)

Output

```
Array
(
    [six] => Array
        (
            [donnes_table_two] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [denomination_de_vente] => value
                            [marques] => value
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [denomination_de_vente] => value
                            [marques] => value
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: While this is a working solution, it is generally advised to not manipulate a json string directly, but to decode, manipulate, then re-encode.  The risks are minimal in this perceived case, but this approach may damage data integrity or invalidate the json string if used elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way too:

```
<?php
$str = <<<EOD
{
    "six": {
        "donnes_table_two": [
            {
                "denomination_de_vente": "value",
                "marques": "value"
            },
            {
                "denomination_de_vente": "value",
                "marques": "value"
            }
        ]
    }
}
EOD;

print '<pre>';
$response = json_decode($str, true);
print_r('Before:');
print_r($response);
$array = array_map(function ($x) {$x['id'] = 1; return $x; }, $response['six']['donnes_table_two']);
$response['six']['donnes_table_two'] = $array;
print_r('After:');
print_r($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **array_map** function

```
$json = '{
    "six": {
        "donnes_table_two": [
            {
                "denomination_de_vente": "value",
                "marques": "value"
            },
            {
                "denomination_de_vente": "value",
                "marques": "value"
            }
        ]
    },
    "seven": {
        "donnes_table_two": [
            {
                "denomination_de_vente": "value",
                "marques": "value"
            },
            {
                "denomination_de_vente": "value",
                "marques": "value"
            }
        ]
    }
}';

$jArray   = json_decode($json, true);
$newArray = array_map(function($element){

  $element['donnes_table_two'][0] = array_merge(
                                    array('id' => 1), 
                                    $element['donnes_table_two'][0]
                                );
  $element['donnes_table_two'][1] = array_merge(
                                    array('id' => 1), 
                                    $element['donnes_table_two'][0]
                                );

return $element;
}, $jArray);


echo '<pre>';
print_r($newArray);
```

Result:-

```
 Array
 (
    [six] => Array
    (
        [donnes_table_two] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [denomination_de_vente] => value
                        [marques] => value
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [denomination_de_vente] => value
                        [marques] => value
                    )

            )

    )

[seven] => Array
    (
        [donnes_table_two] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [denomination_de_vente] => value
                        [marques] => value
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [denomination_de_vente] => value
                        [marques] => value
                    )

            )

    )
  )
```